# Silent Install for QGIS version 3.10

Tags: qgis, installation

I've seen some past comments that a `/s` option is available to silently install the app. However, that doesn't work with the latest stable version. Does QGIS support a built-in silent install method?

Comment: Which operating system?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you may use the recipe from https://gist.github.com/mdouchin/fe2862d39b6c4d04da6f62727cd30b86

It downloads the OSGeo4W installer, downloads the packages for QGIS and does the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a sysadmin and I used `/quiet` in order to install this on a client without interface.